# sample fabric (fabfile) to share common logic and allow multiple projects/environments

Tags: python, deployment, capistrano, fabric

i am new to python and fabric. we currently use capistrano and have a setup similar to this:

```
/api-b2b
  - Capfile (with generic deployment/setup info)
  /int - target host config (like ip, access etc.)
  /prod - target host config (like ip, access etc.)
  /dev - target host config (like ip, access etc.)
/api-b2c
  /int
  /prod
  /dev
/application1
  /int
  /prod
  /dev
/application2
  /int
  /prod
  /dev
```

we are not happy with capistrano for handling our java apps - fabric looks like a better (simpler) alternative.

all the example fabfiles i have seen so far are "relatively simple" in that they only handle one application for different hosts. i'd like to see some code where different app/hosts are handled by the same fabric files/infrastructure (like inheritance etc.) to share the same logic for common tasks like git handling, directory creation, symlinks etc.. i hope you get what i mean. i want the whole logic to be the same, just the apps config is different (git repo, target directory). all the rest is the same accross the apps (same server layout...)

i want to be able to enter something like this

```
$ cd api-b2b
$ fab env_prod deploy
$ cd api-b2c
$ fab env_prod deploy
```

or

```
$ fab env_prod deploy:app=api=b2b
$ fab env_prod deploy:app=api=b2c
```

any help (and pointers to sample files) highly appreciated

cheers
marcel

Answer (score 5):

If you genuinely want reuse amongst your fabric code, the most robust approach is to refactor the commonalities out and make it a python module. There are modules like [fabtools](https://github.com/ronnix/fabtools) and [cusine](https://github.com/sebastien/cuisine) that are good examples of what it is possible to do.

If you're looking to have multiple projects, there are a few ways to achieve that result. Assuming you're using a fabfile directory (rather than a single fabfile.py), you'll have a structure like this.

```
/fabfile
  __init__.py
  b2b.py
  b2c.py
```

Assuming that you have:

```
# b2b.py / b2c.py
from fabric.api import *

@task
def deploy():
    # b2b/b2c logic
    pass
```

When you run `fab -l` (with an empty `__init__.py`) you'll see:

```
Available commands:

    b2b.deploy
    b2c.deploy
```

To get closer to what you're looking for, you can dynamically lookup, from an argument, which deployment target you want to run:

```
# __init__.py 
from fabric.api import *
import b2b
import b2c

@task
def deploy(api):
    globals()[api].deploy()
```

Which means that on the command line, I can run `fab deploy:api=b2b` or `fab deploy:api=b2c`.

---

**Edit 27th Jan**

Specifying one or machines for a task to run on can be achieved on the command line with the `-H` or `-R` switches, using `@task` or `@role` decorators, or the settings in the fabric environment (env.hosts and env.roles). The fabric documentation has extensive examples on the [execution model](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/usage/execution.html#using-execute-with-dynamically-set-host-lists) that shows you all the details.

One way to do this (and potentially not the best way depending on your application) is to [dynamically](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/usage/execution.html#using-execute-with-dynamically-set-host-lists) [alter](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/usage/execution.html#the-alternate-approach) the host lists based on the api and the target environment.

```
# __init__.py
from fabric.api import *
import b2b
import b2c

@task
def deploy(api, target='test'):
    func  = globals()[api].deploy
    hosts = globals()[api].deploy_hosts(target)
    execute(func, hosts=hosts)
```

And now the `b2b.py` and `b2c.py` files will look something like:

```
# b2b.py / b2c.py
@task
def deploy():
    # b2b/b2c logic
    pass

def deploy_hosts(target):
    return {
        'test' : ['localhost'],
        'prod' : ['localhost'],
        'int'  : ['localhost'],
    }[target]
```

Comment: hey andrew, thanks for your answer. where is the int/prod/dev in this scenario. i want to do something like: fab env_prod deploy:app=api-b2b

Comment: @Marcel - are int/prod/dev hosts or roles or something more complex?

Comment: in the end they are just different target hosts. they all share the same directory layout etc.

Comment: hey andrew, maybe the hint with the roles is what i needed. i've hacked together a little GIST to give you an idea. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a86328bf160155bcffbf please give me your thoughts if this is the way to go. ps: i am new to python - so sorry for this ....

Comment: andrew. any idea (see my last comment)

Comment: @marcel - not how I would have written it, but it's easy to understand what is going on and why. Little things - altering sys.path isn't something that needs to happen often (but understandable in the context). Normally I wouldn't worry about classes for fabric, objects don't carry around enough state to bother (just use modules as a type of namespace). Last thing, getting git to work reliably can be a pain, consider using fabtools http://fabtools.readthedocs.org/en/0.17.0/api/require/git.html